# How to make a div in a flexbox appear in next line?

Tags: css, flexbox

I want the div in the flexbox container to appear in the next line.

I have a drawer div and within that have details div. within details div I want the SVG and span elements to be in one line. If the span element has text more than one line then should fit in next line and the div element after span element should always be below the span element and centered in the list element(no matter span element has text one or more than one line).

Something like below.
[image]

Below is the code,

```
.drawer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    width: 392px;
    top: 55px;
    right: 8px;
    min-height: 40%;
    max-height: 450px;
    margin-left: 16px;

    &::after {
        content: " ";
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 100%;
        left: 83%;
        margin-left: -5px;
        border-width: 14px;
        border-style: solid;
    }
}

.item {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 8px;
    min-height: 49px;
    li {
        list-style: none;
    }
    .details {
        display: flex;
        flex-grow: 1;
        color: #333;
        margin-right: 4px;
     }
 }
<div class="drawer">
    <ul>
        <li class="item">
            <div class="details">
                <svg/>
                <span>sometext</span>
                <div>
                    <div/><img/>
                </div>
             </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Could someone help me solve this? Thanks.

Comment: You can give flex-wrap: wrap; to the parent container and flex-basis: 100% to the div you want to show up in new line

Comment: thanks but this also puts span element with more than one line to next line meaning it put svg to first line in the next line appears span element.

Comment: Add proper HTML code like SVG and <img> also.

Answer (score 1):

Your structure contains too many styles, which I was not sure after looking at the requirement of yours (png attached). 
I have added a simple structure suiting your requirement, please see if it makes sense. 
In case you want something please revert

```css
.drawer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  width: 392px;
  top: 55px;
  left: 8px;
  min-height: 40%;
  max-height: 450px;
  margin-left: 16px;
}

svg {
  border: solid 1px;
}

.drawer::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 83%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 14px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px;
  min-height: 49px;
}

.item {
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
}

.item .details {
  color: #333;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

.media {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.media-body {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="drawer">
    <ul>
      <li class="item">
        <div class="media">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img mr-3" width="64" height="64" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 64x64"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">64x64</text></svg>
          <div class="media-body" style="margin-left:20px;">

            <p> Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis
              in faucibus. </p>
            <p style="text-align:center;"> Center align Text </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
       <li class="item">
        <div class="media">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img mr-3" width="64" height="64" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 64x64"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">64x64</text></svg>
          <div class="media-body" style="margin-left:20px;">

            <p> Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis
              in faucibus. </p>
            <p style="text-align:center;"> Center align Text </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
       <li class="item">
        <div class="media">
          <svg class="bd-placeholder-img mr-3" width="64" height="64" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 64x64"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#868e96"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#dee2e6" dy=".3em">64x64</text></svg>
          <div class="media-body" style="margin-left:20px;">

            <p> Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis
              in faucibus. </p>
            <p style="text-align:center;"> Center align Text </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If this has solved your problem, please accept the answer so that others get also benefited by it and save there time and effort. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The text below will be centred more content on top

```css
.drawer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.drawer_icon {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: palevioletred;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="drawer">
  <div class="drawer_icon"></div>
  <div>
    <span>Some Text</span>
    <p>Centered text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```